# Is there something like "feel+past participle" in english?

Tags: american-english

> "I felt impelled to go on speaking".

In such a case does "impelled" function as an adjective here? So it could be "feel + adj" form ,am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it serves as an adjective. And so almost all in that format.

> Feel blessed 
>  Feel awkward 
>  Feel great... and so on

Comment: +1.  In these cases "feel" acts like "am", making the participle a _predicate adjective_ (one kind of _predicate complement_). Search for these terms in your grammar reference for more examples.

Comment: true...@BrianHitchcock